# Return value in Visual Studio's Autos window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

When I used to develop in C++, I remember that Visual Studio had an entry in its Autos window whenever returning from a function call.  This entry would tell me what value was returned from that function.

One might argue that if a function returns a value, then you should set a variable to that value, i.e.

```
int i = GetRandomInt();
```

But as a contrived example, suppose I wanted to do this:

```
CycleTushKicker( GetRandomInt());
```

Instead of stepping into `CycleTushKicker` to figure out how many lickings my kid gets, I'd just like to know the value as soon as I exit `GetRandomInt`.

Is there a way to get this when using C#?

EDIT -- followed @Michael Goldshetyn's advice and filed a feature suggestion on Microsoft Connect.  You can place your votes here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636130/display-return-value-from-function-in-autos-window-for-c

Comment: +1: this has always bothered me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to see the return value of a function in the Autos pane of VS2010 when using C#. If you want to be able to see this value, you will need to assign it to a temporary variable, and then you will see this variable's value (at least in debug builds).

## Update

[VS2013 now offers this functionality](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Comment: I agree, this is very inconvenient. You may want to consider filing this as a bug on Microsoft connect, although it's more like a lacking feature than a bug.

Comment: Ok, you all can vote on this feature suggestion on Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636130/display-return-value-from-function-in-autos-window-for-c

Answer (score 0):

It is better to just use a temporary variable.

This will allow you to see this in the debugging windows, but also allow you to set a break point, and step cleanly over or through each function individually.

By doing the following:

```
var randomInt = GetRandomInt();
CycleTushKicker(randomInt);
```

You effectively create exactly the same code, but it is much simpler to debug.

Comment: In this particular example, I would agree, but there are always math examples, like `angle = GetAngle1() + GetAngle2()`, where you want to do F11, Shift-F11 quickly a couple of times to see what the individual values are.  It's still readable code, and not necessary to assign temporary variables to each result.